# Can I use Postgres rules to reset session variables before/after queries?

Tags: postgresql

I am using Postgres row based security and I wish to ensure it is not possible for a specific session variable (that holds a tenant id) to remain set in between transactions / queries.

The reason is because the session is shared between user queries - if that session variable is set but not cleared, then it is possible that the next query - which is for a different application user - might be executed using the session variable from the previous query.

I wish to ensure that the only session variables that can be used are LOCAL session variables (which must be used only in a transaction and are temporary and do not remain set in the session after the transaction has ended).

So the solution I have come up with is to use the Postgres rules system, and  clear the session variable using RESET or SET in between every transaction or query. RESET https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-reset.html or SET https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set.html both before and after every SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE query.

Although the Postgres rules system appears to have the capabilities to do this but I cannot find much detail.

As you can see here, a google search doesn't return much useful:

[image]

Can anyone direct me to information that might help me work out how to do this?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

These are really not great matches for a search. I wonder what in the world made you consider rules for this.

You should use [`RESET ALL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-reset.html) or, even better, [`DISCARD ALL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-discard.html).

I think that the idea to set such custom parameters with `SET LOCAL` is a really good one, as long as it is guaranteed that the connection will return to the pool after the transaction ends. The drawback is that an attacker can run `RESET LOCAL` any time and continue working with escalated privileges. A solution might be a proper parameter defined in C code that refuses being reset.